# Update Node Selector field for PODs on the fly

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have been trying different things around k8s these days. I am wondering about the field nodeSelector in the POD specification. 
As I understand we have to assign some labels to the nodes and these labels can further be used in the nodeSelector field part of the POD specification.

Assignment of the node to pods based on nodeSelector works fine. But, after I create the pod, now I want to update/overwrite the nodeSelector field which would deploy my pod to new node based on new nodeSelector label updated.

I am thinking this in the same way it is done for the normal labels using [kubectl label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#label) command.

Are there any hacks to achieve such a case ?

If this is not possible for the current latest versions of the kubernetes, why should not we consider it ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can change the `nodeSelector` values through `kubectl edit deploy [DEPLOYMENT] -n [NAMESPACE] -o yaml`. Once changed, the old pod will be terminated, and the new one will be scheduled on the new node.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While editing deployment manually as cookiedough suggested is one of the options, I believe using `kubctl patch` would be a better solution.

You can either patch by using [yaml](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) file or [JSON](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment) string, which makes it easier to integrate thing into scripts. Here is a complete [reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch).

---

## Example

Here's a simple deployment of nginx I used, which will be created on `node-1`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: node-1
```

#### JSON patch

You can patch the deployment to change the desired node as follows:
`kubectl patch deployments nginx-deployment -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"nodeSelector": {"kubernetes.io/hostname": "node-2"}}}}}'`

#### YAML patch

By running `kubectl patch deployment nginx-deployment --patch "$(cat patch.yaml)"`, where patch.yaml is prepared as follows:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: node-2
```

Both will result in scheduler scheduling new pod on requested node, and terminating the old one as soon as the new one is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the nodeSelector line & save it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).