# What is the merge logic of client-go MergePatch or StragegyMergePatch for map type field?

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

What does the MergePatch or StragegyMergePatch do when patching map type field like labels?

When I use MergePatch or StragegyMergePatch, if I add some labels in yaml file, then transfer the data of the entire yaml file to patch method, it could work. But if I remove some labels from yaml file, then patch, it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Some examples, use case? What exactly you want to achieve? Are you asking something specific for YAML or you asking about specific YAML configuration with Kubernetes?

Comment: @PjoterS, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/116326486?noredirect=1, May I trouble you to have a look at this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have investigate further and many things depends on what exactly you want to do on which `resource`. Documentation might be hard to understand so I will expand it more in this answer.

#### Background

You are referring to [Merge Patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-strategic-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment) where you have example of merge patching (adding additional container) `spec.template.spec.containers`. Below you have [Notes on the strategic merge patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#notes-on-the-strategic-merge-patch).

> The patch you did in the preceding exercise is called a strategic merge patch. Notice that the patch did not replace the containers list. Instead it added a new Container to the list. In other words, the list in the patch was merged with the existing list. This is not always what happens when you use a strategic merge patch on a list. In some cases, the list is replaced, not merged.

> With a strategic merge patch, a list is either replaced or merged depending on its patch strategy. The patch strategy is specified by the value of the patchStrategy key in a field tag in the Kubernetes source code.

Default patch strategy can be found in [Kubernetes API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#-strong-api-overview-strong) or in the Kubernetes source code

Regarding patching `Deployments labels`, since `apiVersion: apps/v1` it's impossible. You can find confirmation in [Deployments - Label selector updates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#label-selector-updates).

> Note: In API version apps/v1, a Deployment's label selector is immutable after it gets created.

If you would try to `update` or `patch` it in `apiVersion: apps/v1` you will get an `field is immutable` error. Only way to change `labels/selectors` is to redeploy whole `Deployment`.

However, if you would use older Kubernetes version with `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1` it could be patched like in [Github example](https://gist.github.com/coresolve/364c80b817eb8d84bfb1c6e2c94d2886).

**Please keep in mind that you also can use more `patching methods`** like `JSON merge patch` or `merge patch using the retainKeys strategy`.

#### Tests

Based on [Documentation Deployment Example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment).

You cannot change `Deployment` labels in `apiVersion: apps/v1`, thus you cannot `patch` it as well.

```
$ kubectl apply -f nginx-second.yaml
The Deployment "nginx-deployment" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"nginx", "test":"test"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable
```

In comments you referred to `Node Selector` which can be patched like in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55357287/update-node-selector-field-for-pods-on-the-fly).

In documentaton [Use a strategic merge patch to update a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-strategic-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment) you can find 2 examples, `container` which `patchStrategy:"merge"`:

> The patch strategy is specified by the value of the patchStrategy key in a field tag in the Kubernetes source code. For example, the Containers field of PodSpec struct has a patchStrategy of merge:

```
type PodSpec struct {
  ...
  Containers []Container `json:"containers" patchStrategy:"merge" patchMergeKey:"name" ...`
```

and `tolerations` example which empty `patchStrategy` field.

> Notice that the tolerations list in the PodSpec was replaced, not merged. This is because the Tolerations field of PodSpec does not have a patchStrategy key in its field tag. So the strategic merge patch uses the default patch strategy, which is replace.

```
type PodSpec struct {
  ...
  Tolerations []Toleration `json:"tolerations,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,22,opt,name=tolerations"`
```

Both examples (with containers and tolerations) are list but difference is when you are using merge it's adding new ones, but when you want to replace, `key` value must be the same.

**patch-tolerations.yaml**

```
$ cat patch-tolerations.yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: disktype
        value: ssd
        test1: testvalue1
        test2: testvalue2
        test3: testvalue3
```

**Replacing using the same keys**

```
$ kubectl get deploy patch-demo -o yaml | grep tolerations: -A 5
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: dedicated
        value: test-team

$ kubectl patch deployment patch-demo --patch "$(cat patch-tolerations.yaml)"

$ kubectl get deploy patch-demo -o yaml | grep tolerations: -A 5
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: disktype
        value: ssd
```

It replaced only values with the same `key`. If you would change `patch-tolerations.yaml` to

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        test1: testvalue1
        test2: testvalue2
        test3: testvalue3
```

You will get an error:

```
$ kubectl patch deployment patch-demo --patch "$(cat patch-tolerations.yaml)"
The Deployment "patch-demo" is invalid: spec.template.spec.tolerations[0].operator: Invalid value: "": operator must be Exists when `key` is empty, which means "match all value
s and all keys"
```

**Tests on StatefulSet**

As you asked about labels, you can change them in `statefulset`. Based on example from Docs [Creating a StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#creating-a-statefulset) with some additional annotations `metadata.labels`.

```
$ kubectl get sts -oyaml | grep labels: -A 3
    labels:
      test: test
      test1: test1
    name: web
--
        labels:
          app: nginx
      spec:
        containers:
---
$ cat patch-sts.yaml
metadata:
  labels:
    run: runtest
    app: apptest
$ cat patch-sts-template.yaml
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        app2: run
        test: test
---
$ kubectl patch sts web --patch "$(cat patch-sts.yaml)"
statefulset.apps/web patched
$ kubectl patch sts web --patch "$(cat patch-sts-template.yaml)"
statefulset.apps/web patched

$ kubectl get sts -oyaml | grep labels: -A 5
    labels:
      app: apptest
      run: runtest
      test: test
      test1: test1
    name: web
--
        labels:
          app: nginx
          app2: run
          test: test
      spec:
        containers:
```

#### Conclusion

You are not able to change `Deployment labels` as those fields are immutable.

When you want to patch something, you have to check which is default `patchStrategy`.

> The patch strategy is specified by the value of the patchStrategy key in a field tag in the Kubernetes source code.

In `merge` patch all informations are mixing, when using `replace` patch, new and old patching objects must have the same `key`.

You can use a few patch methods:

- [Strategic merge patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-strategic-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment)

> In other words, the list in the patch was merged with the existing list.

- [JSON merge patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment)

> A strategic merge patch is different from a JSON merge patch. With a JSON merge patch, if you want to update a list, you have to specify the entire new list. And the new list completely replaces the existing list.

- [Strategic merge patch using the retainKeys](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-strategic-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment-using-the-retainkeys-strategy).

**If this didn't answer your question, please specify what you want to exactly achieve using which version, resource and what you want to patch.**